# Are em and percentage the same thing and are their corresponding defaults defined somewhere?

Tags: html, css

So `em` and `percentage` are both defined in relation to something else.
E.g. with `text-indent` it is in relation to the width of the paragraph. Else where (I think font) in relation to the browser's default size.
So why do both `em` an `percentage` exist if they do exactly the same thing?
Are the items which they are relative in each case (examples I have already given) documented somewhere? How do I know in each case with what the value is relative to?

Comment: http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/

Comment: One detail where there aren't equivalent (because of a buggy browser, not per W3C specification. Yeah you know *which* browser): if you use `em` to set font-size in your CSS (and you should), on the <html> element don't write `0.625em` but use percentage instead (`62.5%`) because `em` will trigger a bug in this browser. em and % are strictly equivalent for font sizes everywhere else in all browsers including this one. Just buggy on html element

Comment: 4 or so years ago we used YUI as a base stylesheet; it used to use exclusively em for font-size.  The trouble was that if you ever change the font-size in an element that is likely to contain other elements (ie div as opposed to h3), then you're left re-changing the size back in all of its children.  It was a nightmare in practice.  We eventually just used px for our sizing.  Besides, we were only ever using em to handle relative spacing for users that changed their magnification but even IE7 handles that natively.

Answer (score 5):

They don't do the same thing. Ems are relative to the element's font size, unless they're specified on the font size in which case it's relative to the parent's font size.

Percentage values are relative to other specific values — which of these varies from property to property. Sometimes, percentages may not even be applicable to certain properties, such as borders, whereas ems can be used anywhere that takes a length quantity.

Comment: So `ems` regardless where they are applied to are always in relation to the font-size?

Comment: But `text-indent` is in relation to the width of the paragraph, not the font-size.

Comment: @Jim: Yes, when you specify it as a percentage. This is stated in the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#indentation-prop